# How can I search documents from google using C# code?

Tags: search-engine, google-search-api

I am currently working on document search in google. I don't want to do HTML parsing at all. However looking for some api which search google documents from internet.

Basically I do have one requirement where there is a task of searching .pdf, .doc files from google search. I have done some googling and found that this cause captcha to be introduce from google and there is limit of 100 query / day.

Is there any free API from google or if not any paid by which i can pass some search query and get the result.

Please note, i don't want HTML parsing at all.

Moreover, Is there any way to overcome the issue of Captch??

Comment: I googled "Google search api" and came up with this link in about 15 seconds: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview. Posting as a comment because mostly link-only answers are generally frowned upon around here.